# Jquery only works if I include jquery file again

Tags: jquery, header

I am trying to apply some jquery to my code....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($('.thickbox'));
</script>
```

But this doesn't work.

I have a jquery.js file included in my header (my header is in a different location than this script) .

The script above only works when I add the jquery.js above my code, but that leaves other functionality that uses jQuery not to work...is there a way to fix this? I am using WordPress for this.

What I am expecting to happen is the an alert box to appear, it does not though, I do not get any errors either.

Comment: How doesn't it work? Do you get errors? What do you expect to happen? What is actually happening? Are you certain your initial include of jquery is using a correct path? Are you certain there is an element with a classname called "thickbox" that is loaded before the above script?

Comment: the alert doesnt appear, I am expecting it you, I do not get an errors, I am expecting the alert to appear, I am using the correct path and thickbox is loaded before the script above.

Comment: Put your code within `$(document).ready(function(){//....})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
jQuery('document').ready(function($){

  alert($('.thickbox'));


});
```

might work

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do the following things, in order to make sure it works:

1. Make sure that the code is surrounded by the .ready event:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('document').ready(function() {
           alert($('.thickbox'));
       });
   </script>
   ```
2. I would also probably make sure that jquery.js is correctly loaded before this file, if putting it right above this file fixes it, but breaks the rest, then something is wrong. Remember that it's preferable to put your code at the bottom of your content, in order to not slowdown the website's loading.
3. Now that I know that you're using WordPress, then the other thing you really need to make sure to do in order to load scripts correctly, is to use the [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and also use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) correctly, otherwise WordPress will not work correctly (it's stupid, I know).

Comment: I am using wordpress and it put that code at the bottom of my footer.php file and it didn't work :(

Comment: I just checked my error console and i got this error `TypeError: $ is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$('document').ready(function() {`

Comment: @user1269625 Oh! So you're using WordPress! In that case you might want to use [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) in order to load other libraries and custom JavaScript.

Comment: @user1269625 If this helped, please make sure to upvote it and approve it as an answer, that way you can properly tell me thanks from within StackOverflow. :)